# Does TeXLive 2021 work with arXiv (as of October 2021)?

Tags: texlive, arxiv

Having changed computer, I'm proceeding to install TeXLive. The version I had on the previous computer was 2020, [which worked on arXiv](https://arxiv.org/help/faq/texlive) (besides some small problems with biblatex style files). I see that TeXLive 2021 is out and of course I'd prefer to install that. Has anyone managed to submit to arXiv in the past months without problems by using sources that compile under TeXLive 2021?

Comment: Well over over 99% of all documents that work in texlive 2020 will work in texlive 2021 (actually for documents, probably closer to 100%, although some packages needed an update) so unless you specifically read the change log to find a new feature and explicitly make use of it in your document you should expect a texlive 2021 document to run in tl2020.  If you have an actual example of a document that causes issues, someone could suggest a workaround. If you install texlive 2020 it will be a frozen copy there are no updates or fixes available via `tlmgr` for old releases.

Comment: Hi @DavidCarlisle , great to know. Then I'll take my chances and go for 2021. By the way thank you all of the LaTeX project for everything you're doing!

Comment: As David said, yes for the most part. Most of arXiv's packages are in a 2020 release version (note that we updated prior to the patches for RevTeX at the end of September 2020, so there are some idiosyncrasies, but it's rare that something that doesn't work in 2020 would work in 2021). The only caveat I can think of off hand are packages that have version requirements such as biblatex (since arXiv doesn't process bibtex manually).

Comment: As an aside: We'll be upgrading to TL 2022 once it is released next year.

Comment: @Jake Hello, I see arxiv is still using TL 2020?

Comment: @becko, yes that is correct. There was talk earlier this year of doing an upgrade to TL 2022 in Q4/Q1-2023, but there's not been a firm roadmap set for that at this stage.